# How to register click on newly generated button from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm generating a list with buttons for every new element.

This part is in a javascript function generating the list. I've given the button a class called adding. I'm expecting a message when I click on a button. Following other entries and pages about this subject have gotten me this far but I need an extra explanation on what I'm doing wrong.

Part of javascript for list (vehicleList.js):

```
  ... + '<input class="adding" type="button" name="vehicle" value="Add vehicle">' + ...
```

Javascript for click (part of html):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.adding').on('click', '.adding', function(){
        alert('Click detected');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this syntax of code you need to target the document (or parent element) by using something like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.adding', function(){
        alert('Click detected');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="adding">click me</button>
```

As you can read [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
>
> ..
>
> **selector**
>
> Type: String
>
> A selector string to filter the descendants of
>   the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null
>   or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected
>   element.

And this will work for dynamically generated button.

Comment: I'm still not getting it to work. My for loop is creating the button by adding it to a string which javascript then writes out on html.

But I also have a test button which is created with the page and that's also dead.

Comment: @AtesTen you tried the first one right ? as it shoud work